# The character can't move due to high friction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, unity3d-2dtools

I have trouble with `PhysicMaterial2D` for the ground and my character. When the character doesn't move, it works as I need (both materials have `friction = 1.0`). But due to high friction value the character can't move.
Of course, I could use more force (`AddForce()`) to move the character but then it will move too quickly on other grounds that uses other materials.

**How is this problem resolved in other games (i.e. many platformers)? Should I set a friction of the character's material to zero when it moves (I haven't another ideas)? Or has it more pretty solution?**

[image: preview]

**P.S.** I tested with higher value of the friction also but it led to the character begun to rotate on the moving.

**ADDED**
I tried to set `boxCollider.sharedMaterial.friction = 0.0f` on the movement and return back to `1.0f` after the user released button **BUT** the character continues to move as with zero friction although in the logger I can see it's `1.0f`.

```
private void Update()
{
    if (!paused)
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !IsOverPauseButton())
        {
            isPressed = true;

            endMovePoint = Input.mousePosition;
            isWalk = GetTouchDistance() > jumpTriggerRadius;

            if (!(isWalk || isJump))
            {
                StartCoroutine(Jump());
            }
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && isPressed)
        {
            boxCollider.sharedMaterial.friction = 1.0f;
            isPressed = false;
            isWalk = false;
            canFlip = true;
        }

        if (isWalk)
        {
            if (!isJump)
            {
                boxCollider.sharedMaterial.friction = 0.0f;
            }

            Walk();
        }

        animator.SetBool(WalkingFlag, isWalk && !isJump);
    }

    if (isWalk && !isJump)
    {
        FixSpeed();
    }

    Debug.Log("Friction=" + boxCollider.sharedMaterial.friction);
}
```

Comment: Most of the time, a game character, especially players ones, don't follow the physics engine but have specific controllers to moves them.

Comment: @Kamalen, I can get what do you mean, it suits for simple platformers but, unfortunately, my game requires 2D physics in many things because the main idea of this game bases on the physics.

Comment: This does not excludes physics. You can make a custom controller script that still interact with all others objects. It will be way less hard to have entities partially outside the physics than bending the rigid physics system to match your needs

Comment: @Kamalen thank you! I'll think about it

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using friction, you can dampen the player's movement.

Say your player has a velocity of 10, you want the player to stop moving of it's own accord because that's what's natural.

What you would want to do is subtract an amount from your player's velocity every frame e.g.

`player.velocity.x *= 0.9f;`

This would set the player's x velocity to 90% of it's original velocity. Do this every frame and soon your player will stop all by itself.

If the above method does not produce the effect you desire, you can always just subtract an arbitrary value from the player's velocity (of course you must account for if the player's velocity is negative):

`player.vel.x -= 1;`

Both of the methods above can factor in friction if need be, simply multiply the percentage or arbitrary value by the friction coefficient plus or minus a bit to suit your needs.